# Can Indy load SSL certificate from cryptografic card or token?

Tags: delphi, ssl, certificate, indy

My application is written using Delphi 2007 and Indy 10.  It uses certificates in `.p12` files. I set Indy's `CertFile`, `KeyFile` and `RootCertFile` properties and everything works great.

But soon, it will be used for certificates stored on cryptographic cards or tokens.

Can Indy load SSL certificate from a cryptographic card or token?

If not, how can I improve the application to use a certificate stored on a cryptographic card or token?

Comment: Are the stored certificates public key certificates? If yes there should be a documented way to access (read) them.

Comment: I have not received them yet. I think that will have the same elements: cert, key, rootcert, but stored on other media. I do not know how to read them and pass to Indy.

Comment: Indy does not currently support certificates/keys in non-file media. You may have to resort to using the OpenSSL API directly to manually load your certificates/keys from the cards/tokens. Internally, Indy manually loads and parses certificate/key files into memory using OpenSSL functions like `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey()`, `d2i_PrivateKey_bio()`, `PKCS12_parse()`, etc, and then uses `SSL_CTX_use_certificate()` and `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey()` to load them into OpenSSL sessions. You should ask in the OpenSSL community how to deal with your cards/tokens properly.

Comment: Remy, thank you for pointing direction. Regards.